# Find closest given date in a list of dates

Tags: jquery, date, timeline

I'm creating a time line that is scrollable horizontally using the jQuery [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin.

I have a calendar as an interface to select a date. When a date is selected, I would like to scroll to the closest date in the timeline.

How would I find the closest date in the timeline to the selected date? 
What is the best date format to use for the calculation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript dates have a [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) function which returns the date represented as epoch, or put simply a number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

It is trivial to find the nearest number to a number.... its some basic difference.